# How to define end-of-file in a Lark grammar?

Tags: python, parsing, lark-parser

Suppose I am trying to define a grammar for text like this (simplified example):

```
foo=bar


baz=x
y=z
```

The goal is to be able to parse, modify and write back data like this. I want to preserve whitespace.

My current grammar is something like:

```
NL: "\n"
text: (element NL*)*
element: /\w+/ "=" /\w+/ NL
```

This works if the input ends with a blank line, but I want to accept input that doesn't. But if I change `element` to `/\w+/ "=" /\w+/ NL?` this creates ambiguity. I would do something like:

```
EOF: ""
element: /\w+/ "=" /\w+/ (NL | EOF)
```

But of course the parser doesn't accept an empty string. Furthermore, what I want is not `""`, but an end-of-file token.

How do I define such a thing in Lark?

Comment: When the subject of EOF comes up, it's usually for this specific situation. And in my experience, appending `\n` to every input string ends up being the easiest solution, with no real downsides. But if you really want EOF, you can install this PR which I never merged: https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/pull/880

Comment: @Erez Ah, interesting - so you're saying after I read my input but before feeding it into Lark, just check if there's a terminal blank line and add one if not? That is what I was thinking as well. My other idea was to make every elemnt *start* with a newline rather than end, but then I have the problem with a newline in the beginning (although that one's easier to do a hacky fix for).

Comment: Yes, that's right. Often I just add a newline without checking, since most languages allow empty lines, and aren't affected by them.